# Orthonormal Basis help

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Ω = [−1, 1] ⊂ R and consider Π2(Ω) and given that B = {p1, p2, p3} is a basis of Π2(Ω) and that  = f(−1)g(−1) + f(0)g(0) + f(1)g(1) 
does defines an inner product on Π2(Ω), consider the following:

Show that B is not an orthonormal basis of (Π2(Ω),<.,.>).

I'm not very confident with orthonormal basis' so any help to try and make me answer this question will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Pi2(\Omega)$ supposed to be?

Comment: Anyway, to show something is not an orthonormal basis for something else, you have to show 1) that it's not a basis, or 2) that its elements don't have norm 1, or 3) that its elements are not mutually perpendicular.

Comment: Gerry Myerson, which one of your 3 methods would you use for this question??

Comment: The one that works. But since your question is incomprehensible, I can't tell you which one that is. In any event, it's not an either/or; you try one, if it fails, you try another, and so on.

Comment: If you were me, how would you start the question?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson $\Pi2(\Omega)$ is a **(non standard !!!)** symbol for polynomial with degree $\leq 2$ on $\Omega$. Is that exact ?

Comment: I would start the question by understanding the question well enough to be able to write it up in such a way that other people could understand what the question is. Since I don't know what your notation is, and I don't know what $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are, how can I possibly start to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of polynomials $P_1=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1$ and $P_2=a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2$ is

$$P_1.P_2=(a_1 - b_1 + c_1)(a_2 - b_2 + c_2) + c_1 c_2 + (a_1 + b_1 + c_1)(a_2 + b_2 + c_2)$$

or

$$P_1.P_2=2a_1a_2 + 2b_1b_2 + 2a_2c_1 + 2a_1c_2 + 3c_1c_2 \ \ \ (1)$$

and the corresponding (squared) norm:

$$\|P\|^2=2a^2+2b^2+4ac+3c^2 \ \ \ (2)$$

which is definite positive, because it can be written $2(a+c)^2+2b^2+c^2$ (always $>0$ but for $a=b=c=0$): it's a "full fledged" inner product.

As I dont know what you call $p_1,p_2,p_3$, I am blocked...

May be they are $1=0x^2+0x+1,x=0x^2+1x+0,x^2=1x^2+0x+0$, so it suffices to replace in (1) or in (2) to find a contradiction, for example that the norm of polynomial $p=x^2$ is not 1...

But if you want to find now an orthonormal base with respect to this dot product, here is a method:

- 1) begin by finding an orthogonal base (it will be time enough at the end to normalize to one the norms of the vectors).
- 2) Take $p_1=x^2$, then  check that all $p$ of the form $p=\alpha x^2+\beta x - \alpha$ are orthogonal to $p_1$ (with respect to inner product (1)). The set of such polynomials $p$ is a 2-dimensional subspace $E$. $p_2$ and $p_3$ should be found in $E$...

Comment: think p1,p2,p3 would be 1,x,x^2 due to Π2(Ω)

Comment: "Think p1,p2,p3 would be 1,x,x^2" $\rightarrow$ it is exactly the assumption I have made in "Maybe they are...". You have not said if the solution I propose is convenient or not for you.

Comment: Could you say if my solution agrees you. If such is the case, please check in the margin (green check sign) to signify others that you have a satisfying answer. It is the way this site works.